# Shading between polar graphs

Tags: plotting, filling

Since `PolarPlot` doesn't support `Filling`, what is the best way to shade or fill the a region between two polar curves?

For instance, how would I generate a version of the following graph with the region inside the first curve but outside the second curve filled?

```
PolarPlot[{{1, -1} Sqrt[2 Cos[t]], 2 (1 - Cos[t])}, {t, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: In the first one there are _two_ curves ... :)

Comment: @belisarius: :) okay, true, but [I was actually dealing with `r^2==2Cos[t]` as my first curve](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/140674/72) and for purposes of the region to be shaded, we could actually toss out the negative square root part.

Comment: It appears I misunderstood the question.  Should I leave my answer or delete it?  Perhaps it illustrates *something* of value.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: It definitely adds value—if you take out the `Reverse@`, the part left in white is the part I'd wanted to shade, so with only a little more tweaking, I can get it to do what I'd wanted.

Comment: Thanks.  Though not robust at least that is on-topic; I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: I actually suspect that though it may not be mathematically robust, it's not without its advantages.  If I understand the code correctly, it essentially picks out the individual curves as graphics objects and sets fills on each one.  I could see getting the correct union, intersection, disjunction, etc., of various sets of graphs much more easily by just filling the graphs in the correct order than by figuring out how to set up a parameterization/inequality to shade the correct region.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have a (or more) curves. If you don't use `PolarPlot` you could use `ParametricPlot` instead but you would have to make the transformation from polar coordinates by yourself.

Knowing this, you could think about what your functions mean. For instance `2 (1 - Cos[phi])` is just the radius of your curve for a given `phi`. If you want to draw the region outside your curve, the only thing you have to do is (attention, I'm mixing polar and Cartesian coord.):

Check a every point $\{x,y\}$ whether the radius $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$  is larger than $2(1-\cos(\varphi))$  where $\varphi=\arctan(y/x)$.

Using this, your filling can be achieved with `RegionPlot` and your graphics

```
Show[
 PolarPlot[Evaluate[{{1, -1} Sqrt[2 Cos[t]], 
   2 (1 - Cos[t])}], {t, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}],
 RegionPlot[
  Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] > 2 (1 - Cos[ArcTan[x, y]]) &&
  Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] < Re@Sqrt[2 Cos[ArcTan[x, y]]]
  , {x, -2, 2}, {y, -3, 3}],
 PlotRange -> All
 ]
```

[image]

If you encounter dark mesh lines in the filling and want to get rid of them, please read the [question of david here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/91634/187). You then have to include

```
Method -> {"TransparentPolygonMesh" -> True}
```

as option.

Comment: This no longer seems to work in Mathematica 10.2.

Comment: @David Fixed it. The behavior-change is not documented

Comment: You need to add `Method -> {"TransparentPolygonMesh" -> True}` at the end.

Comment: @David Why would I need it? For me on Linux with *Mathematica* version 10.2 it [looks like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/CQDHU.png) which is except of the default colors exactly what the OP asked for.

Comment: If you look at the first image at [http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91634/mathematica-10-2-problem-with-shading-between-polar-graphs?noredirect=1#comment249007_91634](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91634/mathematica-10-2-problem-with-shading-between-polar-graphs?noredirect=1#comment249007_91634) you will see that the shaded region has a whole bunch of mesh lines. Your new code has those mesh lines on the mac (and probably windows) in Mathematica 10.2. The `Method -> {"TransparentPolygonMesh" -> True}` gets rid of those mesh lines.

Comment: @David One of the rare cases where the Linux version works correctly. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 22):

Even if `Filling` were an option in `PolarPlot`, you won't be able to create such a plot because for 2D graphics, `Filling` just blindly fills along the y-axis, whereas you need to check for an inequality here.

That said, here's another approach that's in the same spirit as halirutan's, but you don't have to convert to Cartesian, etc.

```
eqns[t_] := { Sqrt[2 Cos[t]], 2 (1 - Cos[t])};
region = PolarPlot[Evaluate@eqns[t], {t, -π, π}, 
    RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, t, r}, {#1 > #2} & @@ Re[eqns[t]] // First]];
pts = Cases[region, Line[x___] :> x, Infinity];
colors = {Darker@Green, Blue};

Show[
    PolarPlot[Evaluate@eqns[t], {t, -π, π}, PlotStyle -> colors], 
    ListLinePlot[pts, PlotStyle -> colors, Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> LightGreen], 
    PlotRange -> All
]
```

[image]

Comment: This no longer seems to work in Mathematica 10.2.

Comment: @David Could you show me a screenshot of what you get? I have 10.1 and it produces the same figure above.

Comment: @TheToad David posted this issue as a question here, if you have time to take a look: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91634/mathematica-10-2-problem-with-shading-between-polar-graphs?noredirect=1#comment249007_91634

Comment: @TheToad I posted the image for you at [http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91634/mathematica-10-2-problem-with-shading-between-polar-graphs?noredirect=1#comment249007_91634](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91634/mathematica-10-2-problem-with-shading-between-polar-graphs?noredirect=1#comment249007_91634).

Comment: @David Thank you, and wow! That is absolutely bizarre. Although I have used `Evaluate` in the second call to `PolarPlot`, I haven't in the definition for `regions`. Could you please check if adding `Evaluate` to that line fixes things in 10.2? And if so, please feel free to edit my answer to add the missing `Evaluate` :)

Comment: @TheToad The second Evaluate worked and I added it to your code.

Answer (score 17):

Just another way:

```
<< VectorAnalysis`;
{rho, t, z} = CoordinatesFromCartesian[{x, y, z}, Cylindrical]
Quiet@Show[
  PolarPlot[{ Sqrt[2 Cos@t], 2 (1 - Cos@t)}, {t, -Pi, Pi}],
  RegionPlot[ Sqrt[2 Cos@t] > rho > 2 (1 - Cos@t), {x, 0, 2}, {y, -1, 1}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 16):

Yet another way. It's similar to belisarius's solutions but doesn't require an inverse coordinate transformation

```
Show[
 PolarPlot[{Sqrt[2 Abs[Cos[t]]], 2 (1 - Cos[t])}, {t, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}], 
 RegionPlot[4 (1 - Cos[t])^2 < r^2 < 2 Cos[t], {r, 0, 3}, {t, -Pi, Pi},
  PlotPoints -> 30] /. 
   GraphicsComplex[a_, b__] :> GraphicsComplex[#1 {Cos[#2], Sin[#2]} & @@@ a, b]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 15):

You can parameterize your polar functions on to discs, and then shade appropriately.

```
ρ[t_] := Sqrt[2 Cos[t]];
σ[t_] := 2 (1 - Cos[t]);
ParametricPlot[{{r Cos[t] ρ[t], r Sin[t] ρ[t]}, {r Cos[t] σ[t], r Sin[t] σ[t]}}, 
    {t, -π, π}, {r, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {{Opacity[.5], Red}, {Opacity[1], White}}, 
    Mesh -> None, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 14):

Here's a meager attempt that will soon be humiliated by Heike's answer. ;-)

```
g = PolarPlot[Evaluate@{{1, -1} Sqrt[2 Cos[t]], 
    2 (1 - Cos[t])}, {t, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}];

Graphics[{
   {Pink, Rectangle[Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{1, 1}]]},
   Thread@{{White, Green, Blue}, 
     Reverse@Cases[g, Line[x__] :> Polygon[x], ∞]}
   }];

Show[g, %, g]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Seeing as I misunderstood the question, here is an admittedly fragile way to shade the correct region:

```
g = PolarPlot[Evaluate@{{1, -1} Sqrt[2 Cos[t]], 2 (1 - Cos[t])}, {t, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}];

f = Graphics[Thread@{{Yellow, White, White}, Cases[g, Line[x__] :> Polygon[x], ∞]}];

Show[g, f, g]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @MrWizard This no longer seems to work in Mathematica 10.2.

Comment: @David Thanks for the warning.  These still work in 10.1 under Windows; can you try to figure out what changed?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what the problem is, just experienced it, but Michael E2 may be doing some work [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91634/mathematica-10-2-problem-with-shading-between-polar-graphs?noredirect=1#comment249007_91634).

Comment: Added Evaluate to your code and it now works to give the posted images.

Answer (score 14):

How about

```
dt = Pi/99;
pts = Join[
   Table[2 (1 - Cos[t]) {Cos[t], Sin[t]},
    {t, 0, -Pi/3 + dt, -dt}],
   Table[Sqrt[2 Cos[t]] {Cos[t], Sin[t]},
    {t, -Pi/3, Pi/3, dt}],
   Table[2 (1 - Cos[t]) {Cos[t], Sin[t]},
    {t, Pi/3, dt, -dt}]
   ];
PolarPlot[{Sqrt[2 Cos[t]], 2 (1 - Cos[t])}, {t, -\[Pi], \[Pi]},
 Prolog -> {LightGray, Polygon[pts]},
 PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Combining `ListLinePlot`, `Filling` and `Overlay`:

```
   pnts = Cases[
      PolarPlot[{{1, -1} Sqrt[2 Cos[t]], 2 (1 - Cos[t])}, {t, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}],
     _Line, {0, Infinity}];
   Table[ListLinePlot[{Join[pnts[[1, 1]], pnts[[2, 1]]], pnts[[3, 1]]}, 
     Filling -> fllng, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green},  AspectRatio -> 1], 
   {fllng, {Automatic, {1 -> {Axis, White}}, {2 -> {Axis, White}}, {1 -> {Axis, Red}},
    {2 -> {Axis, Green}}}}]
```

gives

[image]

With `Overlay` and

```
  GraphicsRow[{Overlay[%[[{4, 3}]]], Overlay[%[[{5, 2}]]]}]
```

we get

[image]

Comment: Your code no longer produces these images in Mathematica 10.2. Using `PolarPlot[Evaluate@{{1, -1} Sqrt[2 Cos[t]], 2 (1 - Cos[t])}` does produce your images.

Answer (score 1):

I've used an general and light method, using polygons:

```
regionpoly[cv1_,cv2_,a_,b_,n_: 30,op_:0.5,col_: Green] := Module[{polys, ds},
       ds = N[(b - a)/n];
       polys = Table[Polygon[{
           cv1 /. {t -> dt}, 
           cv1 /. {t -> dt + ds}, 
           cv2 /. {t -> dt + ds},
           cv2 /. {t -> dt}, 
           cv1 /. {t -> dt} }],
           {dt, a, b - ds, ds}];
       (*Return*)
       {EdgeForm[], FaceForm[col], Opacity[op], polys}
       ];

    r1[t_] = Sqrt[2 Cos[t]]*{Cos[t], Sin[t]};
    r2[t_] = 2 (1 - Cos[t])*{Cos[t], Sin[t]};

    Show[{
      Graphics[  regionpoly[r1[t], r2[t], -Pi/3, Pi/3] ],
      PolarPlot[{Sqrt[2 Cos[t]], 2 (1 - Cos[t])}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]                     
      }, Axes -> True, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[0.04]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Show[PolarPlot[{-Sqrt[2 Cos[t]],Sqrt[2 Cos[t]],2(1-Cos[t])},{t,-\[Pi],\[Pi]}],ParametricPlot[r {Cos[t],Sin[t]},{t,-Pi/3,Pi/3},{r,Min[a={Sqrt[2 Cos[t]],2(1-Cos[t])}],Max[a]}],PlotRange->All]
```