# How to fill the closed region by ParametricPlot with solid color?

Tags: parametric-functions, computational-geometry

I am interested in the following implicit curve with parametric equation:

$$
\left\{\quad
\begin{array}{rl}
x=& 9  \sin 2 t+5 \sin 3 t \\
y=& 9 \cos 2 t-5 \cos 3 t \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

ParametricPlot code:

```
ParametricPlot[
 u {9 Sin[2 t] + 5 Sin[3 t], 9 Cos[2 t] - 5 Cos[3 t]}, {t, 0, 
  2 Pi}, {u, 0, 1}, MeshFunctions -> {Sqrt@(#1^2 + #2^2) &}, 
 Mesh -> {{1}}, PlotPoints -> 30, MeshStyle -> Cyan, 
 MeshShading -> {Cyan}, PlotStyle -> Cyan]
```

produces:

[image]

How can I remove those lines inside the closed region? or at least let it be the same color as the filled color?

Additionally, for a given point $P=(x_0,y_0)$, how to determine by Mathematica whether $P$ is inside the filled region or not?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
plt = ParametricPlot[ u {9 Sin[2 t] + 5 Sin[3 t], 9 Cos[2 t] - 5 Cos[3 t]}, 
  {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {u, 0, 1}, MeshFunctions -> {Sqrt@(#1^2 + #2^2) &}, 
  Mesh -> {{1}}, PlotPoints -> 30, MeshStyle -> Cyan, MeshShading -> {Cyan}]
```

[image]

Post-process `plt` to remove `Line`s

```
plt /. Line[_] :> Sequence[]
```

or to paint them `Cyan`:

```
plt /. Line[x_] :> {Cyan, Line[x]}
```

to get

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For the question

> *for a given point P=(x0,y0), how to determine by Mathematica whether P is inside the filled region or not*

we can use the function `testpoint` from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9408/125)

```
testpoint[poly_, pt_] := 
 Round[(Total@Mod[(# - RotateRight[#]) &@(ArcTan @@ (pt - #) & /@ poly), 
        2 Pi, -Pi]/2/Pi)] != 0

poly = Polygon@ Table[{9 Sin[2 t] + 5 Sin[3 t], 9 Cos[2 t] - 5 Cos[3 t]}, 
      {t, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/100}];
{testpoint[poly[[1]], {0, 9}], testpoint[poly[[1]], {0, 0}], testpoint[poly[[1]], {5, 5}]}
(* {True, True, False} *)
```

See also: [How to check if a 2D point is in a polygon?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9405/125)

Comment: thank you. It seems the "InPolygonQ" does not work in my MMA. why?

Comment: @LCFactorization, could be version/os issue. It works in version 9.0.1.0 Windows 8 (64bit). If you have version 10, you can try the new functions as in [Aisamu's answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/65264/125) in the linked Q/A. Thank you for the accept.

Comment: be aware you need to take care how you define insideness for a self overlapping polygon. In this case `InPolygonQ` consideres the inner hexagon region to be outside..

Comment: @george2079, good point, thank you. I replaced `InPolygonQ` with another function from the linked Q/A.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part:

```
ParametricPlot[
 u {9 Sin[2 t] + 5 Sin[3 t], 9 Cos[2 t] - 5 Cos[3 t]}, 
 {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {u, 0, 1}, 
 PlotPoints -> 50, 
 PlotStyle -> Opacity[1, Cyan], 
 Axes -> False, 
 BoundaryStyle -> None]
```

[image]