# Is it possible to color in parts of a parametric plot

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions, filling

I use this code  to plot a parametric plot.

```
ParametricPlot[{2 Sin[t + 3/2 π] + 4/3*Cos[3 t], 
  2 Cos[t + 3/2 π] + 4/3*Sin[3 t]}, {t, -2 π, 2 π}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Proximus Symbool"]
```

[image: What i get]

Now I tried different ways of plotting it and coloring it however none of them work so far. 
So What i actually wanna achieve is this kind of picture:

With this i could explain that you need to calculate the surface between $$+\frac{5\cdot \sqrt{2}}{3}$$ and $$-\frac{5\cdot \sqrt{2}}{3}$$

[image: What i want]

Comment: BTW, you're overplotting your curve; you only need to plot over $[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: [Symbolic area calculation for a parametric self-intersecting closed curve](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88623/symbolic-area-calculation-for-a-parametric-self-intersecting-closed-curve)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `FilledCurve` to color in the line. The simplest method to get the different colors for this example is probably to create the plot twice, with a `RegionFunction` to exclude the inner part for the second plot.

```
plot[col_, opts___] := ParametricPlot[
   {2 Sin[t + 3/2 π] + 4/3*Cos[3 t], 2 Cos[t + 3/2 π] + 4/3*Sin[3 t]}, {t, 0, 2 π},
   PlotLabel -> "Proximus Symbool", opts] /. l_Line :>
   {EdgeForm[{Thick, Blue}], FaceForm[Opacity[1, col]], FilledCurve@l}

Show[plot[Green], plot[Pink, RegionFunction -> (#1^2 + #2^2 > 10/9 &)]]
```

[image]

Comment: Simon, this question looks like a duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/65799/121 -- do you agree?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, yes I agree.