# Shading a sector of a polar graph

Tags: plotting

[This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5087/shading-between-polar-graphs) explains how to shade a region between two polar graphs. Unfortunately my mathematica-fu is too weak to see how it would be used to shade one sector of a single polar graph. Any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ParametricPlot` to get the sector.

```
plot = PolarPlot[1 + 1/10 Sin[10 t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
sectorShade = ParametricPlot[
   r (1 + 1/10 Sin[10 t]) {Cos[t], Sin[t]},
   {t, 0, Pi/4},
   {r, 0, 1}
   ] /. Line -> Polygon
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Show[plot, sectorShade, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The `Line -> Polygon` trick is needed for the color to be solid. Otherwise, the sector will look like this when combined with the polar plot:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can set the style of the sector using `BoundaryStyle`:

```
sectorShade = ParametricPlot[
   r (1 + 1/10 Sin[10 t]) {Cos[t], Sin[t]},
   {t, 0, Pi/4},
   {r, 0, 1},
   BoundaryStyle -> ColorData[97, 2]
   ] /. Line -> Polygon
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Only one question; where do you set color? Is there a system default? If so, where is it set? How do you override?

Comment: @jamesson Good question, this is not obvious because of the `Line -> Polygon` trick. It is the `BoundaryStyle` option that should be used. I added an example to the answer. The default color is given by `ColorData[97, 1]`. If you'd had more curves, they'd use `ColorData[97, 2]`, `ColorData[97, 3]` and so on. You can set the default using `$PlotTheme` (this variable is documented.) There is an answer about creating a custom plot theme [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54545/is-it-possible-to-define-a-new-plottheme).

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a single `ParametricPlot` with two functions as the first argument:

```
ParametricPlot[{r (1 + 1/10 Sin[10 t]) {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, 
  ConditionalExpression[r (1 + 1/10 Sin[10 t]) {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, 0 <= t <= Pi/4]}, 
 {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {r, 0, 1}, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, Mesh -> None, Frame-> False, PlotStyle -> {None, Opacity[1, Red]}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, use a single function with the options `MeshFunctions`, `Mesh` and  `MeshShading`:

```
ParametricPlot[r (1 + 1/10 Sin[10 t]) {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, 
 {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {r, 0, 1}, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, Frame -> False, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {{0, Pi/4}}, MeshShading -> {None, Opacity[1, Red] }]
```

[image]

**Update:** If you have to get the result using `PolarPlot` only, you can make two `PolarPlot`s with different angle ranges and use one of them as the `Prolog` or `Epilog` to the other.

```
PolarPlot[1 + 1/10 Sin[10 t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, Mesh -> None, 
 Prolog -> (PolarPlot[1 + 1/10 Sin[10 t], {t, 0, Pi/4}, 
      PlotStyle -> Red][[1]] /. Line[x_] :> Polygon[Join[{{0, 0}}, x]])]
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jws]

Comment: now if you could only put center axes on that last one!

Comment: Thanks so much, but seems there is a typo (bracket/paren) in that last one, which I cannot find by myself. At least, in 10_4 it will not evaluate as written.

Comment: @jamesson, it works both  in version 9 and 11. It could be some version10 glitch. What error message are you getting in 10_4?

Comment: As it sits, no error message, just red highlighting on one paren and one bracket. Shall I check which?

Comment: @jamesson, could be an invisible line break somewhere  stuck in when you cut/paste code.

Comment: yep, ty. I wish I could accept more than one answer, but so it goes.