# Shading one petal of Cos[3 t] inside of r = 1/2

Tags: plotting

I tried to use some of the techniques [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5087/shading-between-polar-graphs) to shade the area inside the overlap of `r=cos(3t)` and `r=1/2` and was unsuccessful. Even better would be to shade 3 regions; `r = 1/2` for `0<t<pi/6`,`r=cos(3t)` for `pi/6<t<pi/9`, and `r=cos(3t)` for `r > 1/2`

Comment: Please present your problem in terms of the actual Mathematica code you have tried. Pseudo-code does not give enough info about what you might done wrong. In particular, what was the code that produced your plot?

Comment: I considered that, but honestly that would make for quite a long question. I will try and do so later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not define the regions very clearly. This may be what you want.

```
Show[
 RegionPlot[
  {Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] < 1/2 && 0 < ArcTan[x, y] < π/6,
   Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] < Cos[3 ArcTan[x, y]] && π/9 < ArcTan[x, y] < π/6,
   1/2 < Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] < Cos[3 ArcTan[x, y]]},
  {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
  PlotStyle -> {LightBlue, Red, LightGreen},
  PlotPoints -> 150,
  PlotLegends -> Placed[(
     ToString[#, TraditionalForm] & /@
      {r < 1/2 && 0 < t < π/6,
       r < Cos[3 t] && π/9 < t < π/6,
       1/2 < r < Cos[3 t]}), {0.75, 0.85}]],
 PolarPlot[{Cos[3 t], 1/2}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}],
 PlotRange -> All,
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: Yep, exactly it, thank you. Now I can tear it apart to figure out exactly what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

You can plot all the pieces using a single `ParametricPlot`:

```
ParametricPlot[{r Cos[3 t] {Sin[t], Cos[t]}, r/2 {Sin[t], Cos[t]}, 
  ConditionalExpression[r/2 {Sin[t], Cos[t]}, Pi/9 <= t <= Pi/6], 
  ConditionalExpression[r Cos[3 t] {Sin[t], Cos[t]}, Pi/9 <= t <= Pi/6]}, 
 {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {r, 0, 1}, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, Mesh -> None, BaseStyle -> Thick,
 PlotStyle -> {Cyan, Opacity[1, White], Blue, Opacity[1, Red]}]
```

[image]