# How can I fill the region where two polar plots intersect?

Tags: plotting, filling

I'd like to reporduce this image (with shading). Color doesn't really matter.

[image]

Here's what I have so far

```
Show[
  RegionPlot[
    {2 (1 - Cos[3 ArcTan[x, y]]) > 0 && 0 > 2 (1 + Cos[3 ArcTan[x, y]])}, 
    {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
    PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Green},
    PlotPoints -> 150, 
    PlotLegends -> 
      Placed[
        (ToString[#, TraditionalForm] & /@ {2 (1 - Cos[θ]) &&2 (1 + Cos[θ])}), 
        {0.75, 0.85}]], 
  PolarPlot[{2 (1 - Cos[θ]), 2 (1 + Cos[θ])}, {θ, 0, 2 Pi}], 
  PlotRange -> All,
  AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

This produces traces but no fill.

Comment: [A related thread.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5087)

Comment: Yea thats where I got the original code :)

Comment: Then you should have linked to it, since you used code there. :)

Comment: Will do next time. Thanks.

Comment: @Mr. Wizard. With all due respect, I cannot agree with the title change.

Comment: I did not change the title, I *only* added the tag [tag:filling].  You can see the edit history [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/152685/revisions).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
pp1 = ParametricPlot[Evaluate[2 {Cos[t], Sin[t]} # & /@ {1 - Cos[t], 1 + Cos[t]}], 
     {t, 0, 2 π}]
```

Shaded region can be obtained in two ways:

1. Post-process a one parameter `ParametricPlot` constrained to an appropriate region:

For example:

```
sh = ParametricPlot[ConditionalExpression[{2*(1 - Cos[t + π]) {Cos[t + π], 
     Sin[t + π]}, 2*(1 + Cos[t]) {Cos[t], Sin[t]}}, π/2 <= t <= 3 π/2], {t, 0, 2 π}] /. 
     Line -> ({Red, Polygon@#} &)
```

2. Using a two-parameter `ParametricPlot` constrained to the same region:

E.g.

```
sh = ParametricPlot[2 ConditionalExpression[v (1 - Cos[t + π]) {Cos[t + π], Sin[t + π]} + 
      (1 - v) (1 + Cos[t]) {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, π/2 <= t <= 3 π/2], 
    {t, 0, 2 π}, {v, 0, 1}, Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[1], Red]]
```

Then `Show` `pp1` and `sh` together:

```
Show[pp1, sh, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

**Note:**  In both versions,  the option `RegionFunction` can be used instead of `ConditionalExpression` to constrain the plot to the desired region. That is

```
sh = ParametricPlot[{2*(1 - Cos[t + π]) {Cos[t + π],
       Sin[t + π]}, 2*(1 + Cos[t]) {Cos[t], Sin[t]}}, 
       {t, 0, 2 π}, 
       RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, t, r}, π/2 <= t <= 3 π/2]] /. 
      Line -> ({Red, Polygon@#} &)
```

and

```
sh = ParametricPlot[2 v (1 - Cos[t + π]) {Cos[t + π], Sin[t + π]} + 
        2 (1 - v) (1 + Cos[t]) {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, 
        {t, 0, 2 π}, {v, 0, 1},
        RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, t, r}, π/2 <= t <= 3 π/2],
        Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[1], Red]]
```

give the same shaded region.

Comment: You would think (hope?) that there was one technique that would cover all cases.Clearly not. Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: @jamesson, Filling in `PolarPlot` is a  challenging problem, and I am afraid I don't know any general technique.

Comment: That's why my cloud storage now contains quite a few of these =P

Comment: Would it be too much trouble if I asked you to go through " # & /@ "? Seems like a lot of useful things in a small space :).

Comment: @jamesson, thank you for the accept. The pure function `2 {Cos[t], Sin[t]} # & `  with a single (unnamed) argument simply multiplies that argument with `2 {Cos[t], Sin[t]}`.   See also [Function](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html) and [Slot](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Slot.html).  If you give a name to this function, say  `f = 2 {Cos[t], Sin[t]} # & `, the expression `f /@ {a, b}`  maps `f` to each element of the list `{a, b}`, to produce `{f[a], f[b]}`. See  also [Map](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Map.html). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

It can be done in terms of the `PolarPlot` too. However, the kglr's shading mechanism is still needed:

```
p1 = PolarPlot[{2*(1 + Cos[θ]), 2*(1 - Cos[θ])}, {θ, 0, 2 π}]; 
p2 = Show[
   PolarPlot[{2*(1 - Cos[θ]), {θ, -π/2, π/2}],
   PolarPlot[{2*(1 + Cos[θ])}, {θ, π/2, 3 π/2}]}]; 
Show[p1,Graphics[{Red,Cases[p2,Line[x_]:>Polygon[x], Infinity]}],PlotRange->All]
```

Comment: OK, so p1 draws the whole of 2*(1+Cos[θ]), whereas p2 also draws 2*(1+Cos[θ]) from π/2 to 3π/2 just for the shading, right?

Comment: @jamesson, yes, the `p2` makes outer contour of the shaded area. Then we transform the `Line` into the filled `Polygon`.

Comment: Izza typo (extraneous curlybrace round the polarplot in show) - tested and working on 10.4

Comment: Izza typo (extraneous curlybrace round the polarplot in show) - tested and working on 10.4

Answer (score 1):

```
Show[
 PolarPlot[{2 (1 - Cos[θ]), 2 (1 + Cos[θ])}, {θ, 0, 2 Pi}],
 RegionPlot[
  With[{r = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], θ = ArcTan[x, y]},
   2 (1 - Cos[θ]) > r && 2 (1 + Cos[θ]) > r
   ],
    {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, PlotPoints -> 60
  ],
  PlotRange -> All
 ]
```

or

```
Show[
 PolarPlot[{2 (1 - Cos[θ]), 2 (1 + Cos[θ])}, {θ, 0, 2 Pi}],
 PolarPlot[Min[2 (1 - Cos[θ]), 2 (1 + Cos[θ])], {θ, 0, 2 Pi}] /. Line -> Polygon,
 PlotRange -> All
]
```

Answer (score 1):

The best answer is coming  - (。・`ω´・)

```
With[{a = {2*(1 + Cos[θ]), 2*(1 - Cos[θ])}}, 
  Show[
    PolarPlot[a, {θ, 0, 2 π}], 
    ParametricPlot[r Min[a] {Cos[θ], Sin[θ]}, {θ, 0, 2 Pi}, {r, 0, 1}], 
    PlotRange -> All
  ]
]
```